# Spectral Representation theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, spectral-theory, fourier-transform, time-series

In order to show that not all auto covariance functions have a spectral density, I am considering the trigonometric stationary time serie
\begin{align}
X_t = A \cos(\omega t) + B \sin(\omega t),
\end{align}
where $A$ and $B$ are uncorrelated random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$. It could be shown that the auto covariance function is given by
\begin{align}
\gamma(h) = \cos(\omega h),
\end{align}
which is not expressible as 
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{ih\lambda} f(\lambda)\ d\lambda,
\end{align}
with $f$ a function on $(-\pi, \pi]$. Therefore, we are interested in the *Spectral Representation theorem*. It says that $\gamma(\cdot)$ can be written as the Fourier transform of a discrete distribution function. (right-continuous, non-decreasing, bounded on $[-\pi,\pi]$) However, I do not get why
\begin{align}
F(\lambda) = 
\begin{cases}
0 \qquad \text{if $\lambda < -\omega$} \\
\frac{1}{2} \qquad \text{if $ -\omega \leq \lambda < \omega$} \\
1 \qquad \text{if $\lambda \geq \omega$},
\end{cases}
\end{align}
i.e.
\begin{align}
\cos(\omega h) = \int_{(-\pi,\pi]} e^{ih\lambda}\ dF(\lambda).
\end{align}
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your $F(\lambda)$ is not increasing, it should that $F(\lambda)=1$, if $\lambda\ge \omega$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Do you know how $F$ is found explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

For your case, the $X$ may be expressed as the sum of finite terms of $A_i\cos(\omega_it)$ and $B_i\sin(\omega_it)$, from the intuition,
you could consider the spectral distribution with the form $F(\lambda)=\sum_{i}[c_i\eta_{\{\omega_i\}}(\lambda)+d_i\eta_{\{-\omega_i\}}(\lambda)]$, where 
$$\eta_{\{\omega\}}(\lambda)=\begin{cases}0,&\lambda< \omega,\\
1,&\lambda\ge \omega.\end{cases}
$$ 
And determine the $c_i,d_i$ by using $\gamma(h)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{ih\lambda}\,dF(\lambda)$ 
For general case(c.f. Blackwell &Davis, *Time Series: Theory and Methods*, 2nd Ed. Springer(1991), p.151, Th4.9.1), there is following formula for $F(\lambda)$(but it is only useful for the uniqueness of $F$)
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{2\pi}\sum_{|j|\le n}\gamma(j)\frac{e^{-ij\lambda_2}-e^{-ij\lambda_1}}{-ij}=F(\lambda_2)-F(\lambda_1).
$$